# c# IEnumerator i do not accept in visual studio 2008

Tags: c#

je travaille avec visual studio 2008,
I have a question regarding IEnumerator,
he did not accept it, and underline in red.
part of the program :

```
foreach (string attribut in liste_attr)
{
  string perim="";
  if (attribut == "grpProfilDn")
  {
    PropertyValueCollection ValueCollection DirEntry.Properties["grpProfilDn"];
    System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator en ValueCollection.GetEnumerator();

    while (en.MoveNext())
    {
      perim += en.Current.ToString();
    }

    utilisateur1 = perim;             
  }
}
```

Comment: Underline which part? And what is the error message (compiler msg) ?

Comment: Where exactly is the problem? And what is the (compiler) error message?

Comment: This `PropertyValueCollection ValueCollection DirEntry.Properties["grpProfilDn"];` is kinda freaky...

Answer (score 1):

There are two interfaces:

- `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator<T>` (generic)
- `System.Collections.IEnumerator` (non-generic)

You appear to be trying to use the first one as if it were non-generic - but it's hard to tell for sure as the code you've posted is invalid in various ways (you're missing things like "=").

More to the point: why aren't you using `foreach`?

Answer (score 1):

You 're missing 2 '=' in:

```
    ...
    PropertyValueCollection ValueCollection = DirEntry.Properties["grpProfilDn"];
    System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator en = ValueCollection.GetEnumerator();
    ...
```

Comment: I *suspect* that's just a cut and paste error - but the above still wouldn't compile, for the reasons given in my answer.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: You are correct. Thank you for pointing out my error.

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you showed exactly *what* was underlined and any messages.

However, this is not correct C# syntax.

To declare and initialize a variable, you need syntax like:

```
TheType variableName = someExpression;
```

I don't see that <kbd>=</kbd> in your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
   string perim = string.Empty;

    foreach (var item in ValueCollection) {
       perim += item.ToString();
    }
```